# Jquery validation for select at least one check box

Tags: jquery, validation, checkboxlist

[image]

I want to validate at least one checkbox has to be selected or else show error and focus. Here is my form:

```
<div class="form-group">Eligible Branch
    <select id="eligiblebranch" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" >
        <?php  $branch = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM r_branch  ORDER BY id_branch ASC");
            while ($branchresult = $branch->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $branchresult['id_branch']; ?>"> <?php echo $branchresult['branch_name']; ?> </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

And here is what I have tried:

```
//Eligible branch
var eligiblebranch = $("#eligiblebranch").val();
if(eligiblebranch=='0')
{
    $("#eligiblebranch").css({"border-style": "solid", "border-color": "red"});
    $("#showMessage").html('Please Enter Eligible Branch');
    $("#eligiblebranch").focus();
    return false;
    }else{
    $("#eligiblebranch").css({"border-style": "solid","border-color": "#E9E9E9"});
}
```

Comment: I can't find any checkbox in your code?

Comment: multiselect , at least one select ?

Comment: Did you try `$("[id*=eligiblebranch] input:checked").length` ?

Comment: as it is multiselect no need to use checkboxes for selecting multiple

Comment: i put that checkboxex for design @shantaram

Comment: no @Loading.. can u plese suggest full code

Comment: Try to use `$("[id*=eligiblebranch] input:checked").length` check the length of selected element in your JS if it's 0 then apply validation.

Comment: length attribute will help you

Comment: Thank you loading it worked again you are helping me out everyday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a code for you to start with...

```js
function validate(){
var gR = $("#eligiblebranch :checked");
  if(gR.length==0){
    alert("Please select atleast one option");
  } else {
    alert("Can submit form");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">Eligible Branch
    <select id="eligiblebranch" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" >
        <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="BB">BB</option>
      <option value="AA">AA</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="Submit" />
```